# scheduled emails 60 days before, 40 days before

Tags: php, laravel, email

I would like to know how, through Laravel, to send scheduled emails to the same person but 60 days before, 40 days before and so on.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you want automated email notification, you will need to use CronJob. Lets,  say for example you want to inform user that his subscription is gonna expire, then in your database table you need to have expires_at column. And in cron job function you can subtract your desired days from expires_at date with Carbon Object like:

```
Carbon::parse($item['expires_at'])->subDays(60);
```

And check this value in `if` statement. If it is today then send email if it is in future then don't do anything. You can check it with `isFuture()` method of Carbon.